# "Хвосты" удалённых программ в реестре Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, реестр, regedit

Установка программы предполагает занесение данных о ней в реестр, после удаления программы данные из реестра никуда не деваются и продолжают в реестре быть. Вопрос: после повторной установки прежде удалённой программы данные о ней в реестре дублируются или просто перезаписываются? То есть, если, к примеру с теченимем времени одна и таже программа удалялась и устанавливалась в систему три раза, в реестре о ней будет три записи или одна?

Comment: Самое главное, что программа может записывать не только в реестр, а например в неиспользуемые участки диска. Поэтому вопрос нуждается в уточнении, о какой программе идет речь?

Comment: О Sublime text…

Comment: Если так волнует целостность данных, почему не пользуетесь portable версией?

Comment: Не то чтоб волнует, просто хотел понять, как это бывает, как жизнедействует.

Answer (score 2):

Смотря как программа написана :)

Но абсолютное большинство разработчиков придумывают стандартный путь в реестре для его программы и перезаписывают его данные, в случае, если они существуют.

С огромной долей вероятности запись будет одна.

Comment: Верно ли понимаю: если стандартно программа устанавливается например, в C:\Program Files, то адрес её записи в реестре жёстко связан с адресом установки на жёстком диске?

Comment: Нет, совершенно.

Как пример - Radmin. Устанавливается в C:\Program Files (x86)\Radmin Viewer.

Его путь реестра, который я смог найти - Компьютер\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Radmin.

Если бы я установил его куда-то в другое место в реестре бы он находился по тому же пути